# CPU strain on reading from pagefile as opposed to RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, performance

Will CPU usage be higher when trying to read more data from the pagefile than the RAM? I'm thinking of upgrading the RAM in my system, however, I'm only willing to do this if it will decrease the overall CPU usage

Scenario: My pagefile can grow up to about 22GB on a daily basis and I have 4GB RAM. Recently I replaced the disk drive in it to a SSD (moving windows onto the SSD and leaving the pagefile to use the older slower HDD) and my average CPU usage went down from 90% to 40%. My theory is that the older HDD works faster for the pagefile as there are less calls to it now that windows has moved, by this logic, upgrading my RAM (to reduce the size of the pagefile) would have the same effect as more data is being read from a faster source (RAM).

My other question is, the system came with a single 4GB stick and has 2 slots overall, I could either buy another 4gb stick (£15) or buy two 8GB sticks (£50) (the board is limited to a max of 16GB). I don't want to waste the extra money if the performance different isnt going to be that great

Lasty, I am correct in assuming that storing a massive pagefile on the SSD is a bad idea (for its limit write life and such)?

Comment: which OS? Reading from page file causes more disk usage, but not CPU

Comment: @magicandre1981 Windows 7

Comment: look at the peak commit value and update the RAM to the size of the peak to keep all requested memory in RAM and avoid paging.